# How to open an SQLite database in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I need a way to open an aleardy built database. I already created the database using some **python** scripts and I need to use this database on my **Flutter** app, but when I try to open the database stored in my android phone it tells me that it's not readable.

Here is my code:

```dart
Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
  print('1');
  Database database = await openDatabase(
    '/storage/emulated/0/Etudes/PFE/Implementation/database/example.db',
    version: 1,
  );
  print('2');
  return database;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _initDatabase();
}
```

And when I run it, it's giving me this error:

> E/SQLiteLog(19872): (14) cannot open file at line 38590 of [d2e6722037]

> E/SQLiteLog(19872): (14) os_unix.c:38590: (13) open(/storage/emulated/0/Etudes/PFE/Implementation/database/example.db) -

> E/SQLiteDatabase(19872): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/storage/emulated/0/Etudes/PFE/Implementation/database/example.db': File /storage/emulated/0/Etudes/PFE/Implementation/database/example.db is not readable

Comment: What type of database? SQLite? MySQL?

Comment: SQLIte @TarHalda

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the file is present under the given link?

Anyway, I would suggest you don’t hard-code your path like this. It would be better to use the given Android-call to get a path to external storage to use. I would suggest checking out `path_provider` package for flutter.(See: https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getExternalStorageDirectories.html)

Comment: Yes, I copied manually the database to that location, plus it tells me that it's can't read it, so it detects it, but how can I use the path_provider in my case

Comment: What Android version are you using? Depending on that you might need to add a Permission to your Android manifest. (See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: And please let me know the error message, if you put something cryptic instead of a „maybe-real“ link as database. Is the error also a `is not readable` if the file is garanteed to not exist?

Comment: I might be talking confusing stuff here, so I will TL;DR my thoughts: If you have an Android version, where the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is required, this might be the cause of the error. If you have a newer Android version, the problem might be, that the path is incorrect. Therefore the idea to test with a nonexistent file, to see if the error messages differ. If they do, the path you hard-coded is incorrect. Then use `path_provider` to generate the path for you. But one step after the other.